# How do I get the unicode/hex representation of a symbol out of the HTML using JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, unicode, hex

Say I have an element like this...

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mo class="symbol">α</mo>
</math>
```

Is there a way to get the unicode/hex value of alpha `α`, `&#x03B1`, using JavaScript/jQuery? Something like...

```
$('.symbol').text().unicode(); // I know unicode() doesn't exist
$('.symbol').text().hex(); // I know hex() doesn't exist
```

I need `&#x03B1` instead of `α` and it seems like anytime I insert `&#x03B1` into the DOM and try to retrieve it right away, it gets rendered and I can't get `&#x03B1` back; I just get α.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using mostly plain JavaScript, you should be able to do:

```
function entityForSymbolInContainer(selector) {
    var code = $(selector).text().charCodeAt(0);
    var codeHex = code.toString(16).toUpperCase();
    while (codeHex.length < 4) {
        codeHex = "0" + codeHex;
    }

    return "&#x" + codeHex + ";";
}
```

Here's an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/btWur/

Comment: @aroth... this looks awesome! i'm testing now

Answer (score 22):

`charCodeAt` will get you the decimal value of the string:

```
"α".charCodeAt(0); //returns 945
0x03b1 === 945; //returns true
```

`toString` will then get the hex string

```
(945).toString(16); // returns "3b1"
```

(Confirmed to work in IE9 and Chrome)

Answer (score 17):

If you would try to convert Unicode character out of [BMP (basic multilingual plane)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) in ways above - you are up for a nasty surprise. Characters out of BMP are encoded as multiple `UTF16` values for example:

`"".length` = 2 (one part for shackle one part for lock base :) )

so `"".charCodeAt(0)` will give you `55357` which is only 'half' of number while `"".charCodeAt(1)` will give you `56594` which is the other half.

To get char codes for those values you might wanna use use following string extension function

```
String.prototype.charCodeUTF32 = function(){   
    return ((((this.charCodeAt(0)-0xD800)*0x400) + (this.charCodeAt(1)-0xDC00) + 0x10000));
};
```

you can also use it like this

```
"&#x"+("".charCodeUTF32()).toString(16)+";"
```

to get html hex codes.

Hope this saves you some time.

Comment: ＋1 Thanks for saving us from this landmine! Checking the length of the character was the key for me.

Comment: Good insight, and note that not just emojis are beyond the BMP :) Your prototype enhancement should probably check the length first; for "UTF-8" strings the `this.charCodeAt(1)` with return `NaN`, and so will the entire function as a consequence; for "length === 2" chars it should just return `charCodeAt(0)` as such.

Answer (score 0):

for example in case you need to convert this hex code to unicode

e68891e4bda0e4bb96

1. pick two character time by time ,
2. if the dec ascii code is over 127 , add a % before
3. return url decode string

   function hex2a(hex) {
       var str = '';
       for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2){

   ```
       var dec = parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16);
       character = String.fromCharCode(dec);


       if (dec > 127)
           character = "%"+hex.substr(i,2);

       str += character;

   }

   return decodeURI(str);
   ```

   }