# How to read Unicode txt file in Javascript/Jquery/Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, unicode

I want to read Unicode text file in `javascript/Jquery/Phonegap`

when I am reading this file, it is giving special character.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Should help you along your way [How do I get the unicode/hex representation of a symbol out of the HTML using JavaScript/jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639770/how-do-i-get-the-unicode-hex-representation-of-a-symbol-out-of-the-html-using-ja)

Comment: Thanks it is working we have used HTML filereader with unicode.