# How to get the entity number from an html entity with js

Tags: javascript, html

I want to convert certain entities to their entity numbers, using javascript. Is there a function to do this? Could I do it for some specific entities?

***Example:***

***I want to output the € entity as its html-entity number: `&#8364;` in the console.***

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w5ocjwv8/)

**html**

```
<div>I want to retreive the euro character from the button, get the html code that belongs to it and output it in the console.log. So the console.log should state: "Euro-symbol: (html code here)!!!"</div>
<button id="alt-char">Euro-symbol: &#8364;!!!</button>
```

**javascript**

```
var a = document.getElementById('alt-char').innerHTML;
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more explanation to the question? At the moment it's a little hard to understand what you want.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I added an example to the question. hope it clears it up a bit.

Comment: look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639770/how-do-i-get-the-unicode-hex-representation-of-a-symbol-out-of-the-html-using-ja

Comment: I managed to fiddle together a solution using charCode and some inspiration from the link from Ines Tlili : https://jsfiddle.net/w5ocjwv8/2/ Thanks everyone for the help :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function charCodeAt will solve your problem.
Check [this](http://www.toutjavascript.com/reference/ref-string.charcodeat.php) out for more details and examples.

Answer (score 5):

I think the function you're looking for is charCodeAt, as in:

```
var str = "€";
var n = str.charCodeAt(); // n = 8364
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers, using `charCodeAt` to retrieve the value of the character is recommended.

Firstly, get the textContent of the desired element:

```
const el = document.getElementById('alt-char').textContent;
```

Secondly, extract all non-standard characters (not exhaustive):

```
const chars = el.match(/[^\w\*!-: .,'"$%^&*@]/g);
```

Lastly, convert the characters into HTML entities:

```
const entities = chars.map(c => ('&#' + (c.charCodeAt(0)) + ';'));
```

Example:

```js
const a = document.getElementById('alt-char').textContent;
const chars = a.match(/[^\w\*!-: ]/g);
const entities = chars.map(c => ('&#' + (c.charCodeAt(0)) + ';'));
console.log(entities);
```

```html
<div>I want to retreive the euro character from the button, get the html code that belongs to it and output it in the console.log. So the console.log should state: "Euro-symbol: (html code here)!!!" </div>
<button id="alt-char">Euro-symbol: &#8364;!!! Pound: &#163;!!!</button>
```