# Javascript: How to extract english words or Chinese characters from a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to extract each character from this string
and output an array

> String = "你is我"

to

> array = ["你", "is", "我"]

How can I do that in javascript?

Comment: `String.match(/\p{Script=Han}+|\p{Script=Latin}+/gu)` in [supporting browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_regexp_property_escapes)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for your problem. If you also want to find other characters, you can add them in the brackets:

```js
const regex = /[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}/gm;
const str = `你is我你is我你is我你is我你is我`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this took some effort but here it is. The idea is to check the unicode of each character. Here I have checked the range of basic Latin English alphabet range. You can go with checking Chinese unicode range as well.

```js
var s = "你is我";

function entityForSymbolInContainer(s) {
    var code = s.charCodeAt(0);
    var codeHex = code.toString(16).toUpperCase();
    while (codeHex.length < 4) {
        codeHex = "0" + codeHex;
    }
    return codeHex;
}

function is_latin_english(s){
  if(entityForSymbolInContainer(s)>='0020' && entityForSymbolInContainer(s)<='007F'){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}

var s_split = s.split('');

var s_result=[];
s_result.push(s_split[0]);
for(var i=1;i<s_split.length;i++){
  if(is_latin_english(s_result[s_result.length-1])==is_latin_english(s_split[i])){
    s_result[s_result.length-1]+=s_split[i];
  }else{
    s_result.push(s_split[i]);
  }
}

console.log(s_result);
```

I used method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6639813/4720652) to obtain the Unicode of each character.

Range used for filtering Latin English characters - https://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0020-007F

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the help of (Spread syntax)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax] and with simple for loop.

```js
const str = "你is我";
//const str = "你is我test     hello";
var splittedStr = [...str];
var arrayLength = splittedStr.length;
var words = [];
var englishWord = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < arrayLength; i += 1) {
    if (/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(splittedStr[i])) {
        englishWord += splittedStr[i];
    } else if (/(\s)+$/.test(splittedStr[i])) {
        if (englishWord !== "") {
            words.push(englishWord);
            englishWord = "";
        }
    } else {
        if (englishWord !== "") {
            words.push(englishWord);
            englishWord = "";
        }
        words.push(splittedStr[i]);        
    }
}

if (englishWord !== "") {
    words.push(englishWord);
}
console.log(words);
```