# Sql script to get English text from script

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column with both English and Chinese text.

Example: The hills have eyes. 隔山有眼

Expected results: The hills have eyes.

How can I extract the English text from that string using sql, please.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Javascript: How to extract english words or Chinese characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58637490/javascript-how-to-extract-english-words-or-chinese-characters-from-a-string), you only need to convert that idea to MySQL, or SQL-server  (you are not clear in your tags about which RDBMS you are using)

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are very different databases.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

A quick-and-dirty way simply converts the string to ASCII and removes the `'?'` -- which is the representation of the other characters:

```
select replace(convert(t.str using ascii), '?', '')
from t;
```

The only downside is that you lose `'?'` characters in the original string as well.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=104537e9d413491a66f3d9ef240c8a91) is a db<>fiddle.

For more control over the replacement, you can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(t.str, '[^a-zA-Z0-9.?, ]', '')
from t;
```

Unfortunately, I am not aware of a character class for ASCII-only characters.

Comment: Thank you for replying. The Chinese charters still appeared in the results.

Comment: @Diamond . . . I included a db<>fiddle showing that this works.

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is to use a function that returns just the english only text.

Additionally, you could make it dual-purpose with another parameter to determine if you want the English text or Non-English text to switch the `<127` comparison.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `EnglishOnly`(String VARCHAR(100)) 
RETURNS varchar(100)
NO SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE output VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE i INTEGER DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE ch varchar(1);

    IF LENGTH(string) > 0 THEN
        WHILE(i <= LENGTH(string)) DO
            SET ch=SUBSTRING(string, i, 1);
            IF ASCII(ch)<127 then
              set output = CONCAT(output,ch);
             END IF;
            SET i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;
    END IF;    
    RETURN output;
END;
```

You can then sinply use it like so

```
select EnglishOnly ("The hills have eyes 隔山有眼that see all.")
```

**Output**

```
The hills have eyes that see all.
```

Example [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e928aeef84ca6d3b39edb7e76254da86)